# Tensorflow Lite 2.3.3 Interpreter->inputs() throws vector access violation

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have successfully build tensorflow 2.3.3.
I extracted the libraries from bazel-out (flatbuffers.lib, tensorflowlite.dll, tensorflowlite.dll.if.lib). Also I pasted the tensorflow/core & tensorflow/lite into the include folder (the same for the flatbuffers headers).

The following code should read a model (the `tflite::PrintInterpreterState` prints all the nodes correctly) and get the size of the input node.

```
std::string modelReference = "../model/od_model.tflite";
std::unique_ptr<tflite::FlatBufferModel> model = tflite::FlatBufferModel::BuildFromFile(modelReference.c_str());
tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver resolver;
tflite::InterpreterBuilder builder(*model, resolver);
std::unique_ptr<tflite::Interpreter> interpreter;
builder(&interpreter);

tflite::PrintInterpreterState(interpreter.get());
const std::vector<int>& t_inputs = interpreter->inputs();
// Does not access t_inputs!
size_t inputSize = t_inputs.size();
int index = t_inputs[0];
TfLiteTensor * inputTensor = interpreter->tensor(t_inputs[0]);
```

This simple main uses the following includes :

```
#include "tensorflow/lite/interpreter.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/kernels/register.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/model.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/optional_debug_tools.h"
```

Unfortunately, I receive a access violation exception during the `.size()` call on the `t_inputs` vector (otherwise `t_inputs[0]` would throw it) . There are a few samples around and they all do this call to get the input size.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I answered my own question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73610444/tensorflow-lite-c-build/73619297#73619297) for those who are curious.

Comment: I'm actually facing the exact same problem. I've built the TFlite with -c dbg from the get go. Could you point out what's the possible reason this would occur?

Comment: You are facing the same errors even though you've built it with 'bazel build -c dbg ...' ? Did you include the correct files? For mine it was working after this fix.

Comment: I was indeed facing the same error  even though I've built it with 'bazel build -c dbg ...', didn't even trying to build it with -c  opt from the first place. The thing is, I  rebuilt it with -c opt flag and the error went away. Of course I haven't tried debugging the whole thing assuming it would not work but for now, I know the library is working fine.