# Tensorflow Lite c++ Build

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have already put a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73486921/tensorflow-lite-2-3-3-interpreter-inputs-throws-vector-access-violation) about the access violation of the TensorFlow lite c++ API. No one answered it so far, I believe the error I made is with selecting the wrong header- and library files from the Bazel build.

The steps that I have done to get the Tensorflow Lite Header and Libraries are from [Youtube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1IhMISYvZG0) and from [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows).

1. Get Required Python (for me Python 3.9.5)
2. Install required Packages locally
3. Install Bazel (for me 3.7.2) and MSYS2 (after installation run `pacman -S git patch unzip`) and add it to Path
4. Check VS Build Tools 2019 for C++ (I have VS 19 Community with MSVC v142 & Windows 10 SDK)
5. Download and Unzip Tensorflow Sources from Github ([Release of 2.5.3](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.5.3))
6. Inside the Tensorflow Sources, use `python .\configure.py` to start configure the bazel build (I only used Yes for  `override eigen strong inline`, the rest is kept on the default value)
7. The I opened GitBash cmd inside the tensorflow source `bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/lite:tensorflowlite`
8. After a successful build later I get the "bazel-bin", "bazel-out", "bazel-tensorflow-2.5.3" and "bazel-testlogs" folder.
9. I created the following folders tensorflow/include/tensorflow/lite & core and  tensorflow/include/flatbuffers for the headers and finally the tensorflow/lib for the libraries.
10. I copied the `tensorflowlite.dll` & `tensorflow.dll.if.lib` from the build directory (tensorflow-2.5.3\bazel-bin\tensorflow\lite) into the tensorflow/lib directory together with the `flatbuffers.lib` (from tensorflow-2.5.3\bazel-bin\external\flatbuffers\src)
11. I copied the tensorflow-2.5.3\bazel-bin\external\flatbuffers\src_virtual_includes\flatbuffers\flatbuffers headers into the tensorflow/include/flatbuffers directory
12. I copied the tensorflow-2.5.3\tensorflow\lite and tensorflow-2.5.3\tensorflow\core from the original sources into the tensorflow/include/tensorflow/lite & core directory.

After those steps, I could create a new VS Project and add the created linker and include information. And created the following short example to read the input layer.

```
#include "tensorflow/lite/interpreter.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/kernels/register.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/model.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/optional_debug_tools.h"

#define TFLITE_MINIMAL_CHECK(x)                                  \
    if (!(x))                                                    \
    {                                                            \
        fprintf(stderr, "Error at %s:%d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__); \
        exit(1);                                                 \
    }

int main()
{
    std::string filename = "C:/project/tflitetesting/models/classification/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_quant.tflite";
    std::unique_ptr<tflite::FlatBufferModel> model =
        tflite::FlatBufferModel::BuildFromFile(filename.c_str());
    tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver resolver;
    tflite::InterpreterBuilder builder(*model, resolver);
    std::unique_ptr<tflite::Interpreter> interpreter;
    builder(&interpreter);

    TFLITE_MINIMAL_CHECK(interpreter->AllocateTensors() == kTfLiteOk);
    printf("=== Pre-invoke Interpreter State ===\n");
    tflite::PrintInterpreterState(interpreter.get());

    interpreter->SetAllowFp16PrecisionForFp32(true);
    interpreter->SetNumThreads(1);
    // Get Input Tensor Dimensions
    unsigned char* input = interpreter->typed_input_tensor<unsigned char>(0);
}
```

But I am still receiving the access violation exception inside `interpreter.h` at

```
  const Subgraph& primary_subgraph() const {
    return *subgraphs_.front();  // Safe as subgraphs_ always has 1 entry.
  }
```

What am I doing wrong? I dont want to build the shared library since the target (Coral Edge) has direct access to those functions (ex. `interpreter->typed_input_tensor<unsigned char>(0);` too.

Answer (score 3):

The thing is, you cannot Debug a Release (Optimized) version.

with the command `bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/lite:tensorflowlite` you will create an "Release" version of the dll's and lib's.

Therefore just apply `bazel build -c dbg //tensorflow/lite:tensorflowlite` to get the debug tflite c++ version.